# Why does the divergence theorem not hold for this vector field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-theorem

$$\mathbf{u}=\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^\alpha},\;div\,\mathbf{u}=\frac{3-\alpha}{r^\alpha},\;\alpha\le3$$
The divergence theorem holds on the unit ball $r\leq 1$ for $\alpha\lt 3$ but not for $\alpha=3$. Why is this?

I can't see how this would break the hypotheses of the divergence theorem as the field is still differentiable on the unit ball.

Comment: Are you sure that "the field is still differentiable on the unit ball"? It looks singular at $0$.

Comment: I can see its singular at zero but this seems to be the case regardless of whether $\alpha \lt 3$ or $=3$

Comment: Right. Some vector fields satisfy the conclusion of the divergence theorem even though they're singular.  But you can't expect them all to be so nice (or so lucky).

Comment: Oh I see so sufficient reasoning is that the vector field isn't differentiable at the origin? Does this mean its a coincidence that it is true for $\alpha \lt 3$ or is there an explanation for that?

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that there's an explanation why the "milder" singularities for $\alpha<3$ get lucky, but I'm not confident that I could produce such an explanation.

Comment: Could it be something to do with the fact that for $\alpha \lt 3$, both $\mathbf{u}$ and its divergence are singular, but $div \mathbf{u}$ is not for $\alpha = 3$?

Comment: That seems unlikely. Consider, for example, the sum of two fields, one with $\alpha<3$ and one with $\alpha=3$. The sum and its divergence will both be singular, but the divergence theorem will fail.